# How do I report the distribution of a variant among genders?

Tags: sociolinguistics, gender, analysis

Just a quick question as I'm slightly confused

If I want to report the use of e.g. [t] among males and females, in a graph, would the percentages be worked out as follows:

males/ all tokens collected for [t]
or
males/ all tokens collected by males for all /t/ variants

An easy question just haven't done it in a while
Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is/what you are asking. Can you give an example? Also, are you sure you mean "collected by males"?

Comment: FWIW, the standard way of calculating a proportion is [number of tokens produced by group 1] divided by [number of tokens produced by all groups]. In addition, you need to control for how much material you have from both groups (say 20 hours of speech produced by males vs 10 hours by females compared to 10 hours by each group).